# SQL Server 2008 - boolean variable change query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @IsStocked bit
SELECT * FROM Products p WHERE p.LastSeen >  GETDATE() - 30
```

This returns all *Products* that have been seen within the last 30 days.

My question is, I would like the `p.LastSeen >  GETDATE() - 30` clause to only apply when `@IsStocked = true`.

This is part of a larger query, and I'd like to achieve this without using IF/ELSE statements (i.e. if `@IsStocked = false` the `p.LastSeen >  GETDATE() - 30` section of the WHERE clause is ignored completely).

Thanks!

Comment: why don'y you want to use an IF/ELSE? The other alternative might lead to an incorrectly cached query plan....

Comment: for simplicity really - there's around 10 variables in the sproc - all of which can be true/false or null - unless there is a way you can suggest that's not going to result in a IF/ELSE for each? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @IsStocked bit

SELECT * FROM Products p
WHERE  @IsStocked = 0 OR (p.LastSeen > GETDATE() - 30);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @IsStocked bit;

SELECT * 
FROM Products p
WHERE (@IsStocked = 1 AND p.LastSeen > GETDATE() - 30) 
OR     @IsStocked = 0;
```

Comment: @Mitch: It's 6:30 AM and I can't get back to sleep.  Gimme a break, man!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Query according to your question

```
DECLARE @IsStocked bit
Set @IsStocked=1
Select * from Product
Where LastSeen  = Case When (@IsStocked=1) THEN GETDATE() - 30 
                   Else LastSeen  END
```

hope that will help.